# ¿Es posible cargar en distintos banner la misma id?

Tags: android, admob

tengo varios activitys y a todos les cargo distintos banners con distintas ids.

¿Es posible cargar en todos los banners la misma id?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si, es posible , pero es algo que no recomiendan.

Comment: Y si creas un layout con el solo AdView y solo lo incluyes en tus activities?

Comment: En realidad lo que preguntas es lo que se realiza comunmente @Orz

Comment: @AndresMartinez estamos hablando de cargar en un layout un bloque de anuncios de tipo banner no? Sin embargo, para el intersticial no podemos cargar ningún layout, serviria poniendo el mismo id?

Answer (score -2):

Lo que comentas es lo que regularmente se realiza, defines un `unitId` de un anuncio en anuncios que defines en tu aplicación, en los cuales solo cambias la medida. Defines el `ads:adUnitId` y defines su medida mediante [`ads:adSize`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize)

Puedes defiir la medida `BANNER` :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"

        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
```

y en otra parte de tu aplicación agregar otro anuncio con otra medida, como `MEDIUM_RECTANGLE` :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"

        ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
```

ambos anuncios usan el mismo unitId y de acuerdo a la medida que definas se mostrará un anuncio de diferente aspecto.

[En realidad el adUnitId es un id de aplicación](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356431).

Comment: Entonces entiendo que el único motivo para crear distintos bloques de anuncio (banners) es para controlar el tipo de anuncio que se muestra (texto ,imagen, video...) ?

Comment: NO, un adUnitId es un grupo de anuncios, por ejemplo a un adUnitId se le pueden relacionar varios anuncios, crear otro adUnitId indica que este tiene otro grupo de anuncios con diferente contenido a desplegar.